# Python Schedule Module - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, schedule

Does anyone know if there is any issues / specific way to get this module to work? I've tried running the same code in NP++, PyCharm & Thonny just to see and Thonny is the only one that it works on I assume because it installs it again to a separate location.

I've pip uninstalled it and reinstalled it. Every other module works absolutely fine.

NP++ the console just does nothing at all.

PyCharm returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Blain\Documents\Python\schedtest2\main.py", line 1, in <module>
import schedule
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule'
```

I've specifically moved the PyCharm project to the folder the libraries are housed in, I've copied the 'working' schedule folder from the Thonny installed location to replace them to see if it had somehow become corrupt and no dice.

Any assistance would be appreciated if anyone had this issue.

for reference just to try get it working the only code I'm running is this snippet from the example on PyPi.

```py
import schedule
import time
def job():
    print("I'm working...")
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple versions of python on your system, but only one of them has the `schedule` module installed.  Thonny is using the version of python that does have `schedule` installed, and PyCharm/NP++ are using other version(s).  Run this code in all three to see what output you get: `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: Also, see if you have a virtual-env set in these, and they must be same!